# Proving or disproving basic facts about infinite series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, solution-verification

I am self-learning Real Analysis from `Understanding Analysis` by Stephen Abott. I'd like to ask, if my proof to the below question on convergence of infinite series is rigorous and sufficient, and checks out.
$\newcommand{\absval}[1]{\left\lvert #1 \right\rvert}$

> Give an example of each or explain why the request is impossible referencing the proper theorem(s).
>
> (a) Two series $\sum {x_n}$ and $\sum{y_n}$ that both diverge but where $\sum x_n y_n$ converges.
>
> (b) A convergent series $\sum x_n$ and a bounded sequence $(y_n)$ such that $\sum x_n y_n$ diverges.
>
> (c) Two sequences $(x_n)$ and $(y_n)$ where $\sum x_n$ and $\sum (x_n + y_n)$ both converge but $\sum y_n$ diverges.
>
> (d) A sequence $(x_n)$ satisfying $0 \le x_n \le 1/n$ where $\sum (-1)^n x_n$ diverges.

***Proof.***

(a) The simplest examples I could come up with are:

(i) $\sum x_n = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n}$ and $\sum y_n = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n}$ are both divergent sequences, but $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^2}$ is convergent.

(ii) $\sum x_n = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n}$ and $\sum y_n = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n+1}$ are both divergent sequences, but $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n(n+1)}$ is convergent.

To see that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n(n+1)}$ is convergent, we simply note that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^p}$ is convergent for $p > 1$, so $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^2}$ is convergent. And $\frac{1}{n(n+1)} < \frac{1}{n^2}$, so by the Comparison test,  $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n(n+1)}$ is convergent.

(b) I think that this request is impossible. The series $\sum x_n$ is convergent. By the Cauchy Criterion, given any $\epsilon > 0$, there exists $N \in\mathbf{N}$, such that
\begin{align*}
 \absval{x_{m+1} + x_{m+2} + \ldots + x_{n}} < \frac{\epsilon}{M}
\end{align*}
for $n > m \ge N$.

Also, the sequence $(y_n)$ is bounded, so $\absval{y_n} \le M$ for all $n\in\mathbf{N}$.

Consider the expression $\absval{x_{m+1}y_{m+1} + \ldots + x_{n}y_{n}}$. We can write,
\begin{align*}
 \absval{x_{m+1}y_{m+1} + \ldots + x_{n}y_{n}} &\le \absval{x_{m+1}\absval{y_{m+1}} + \ldots + x_{n}\absval{y_{n}}}\\
 &\le \absval{x_{m+1}M + \ldots + x_{n}M}\\
 &=M \absval{x_{m+1} + \ldots + x_{n}}\\
 &<M \cdot \frac{\epsilon}{M} = \epsilon
\end{align*}

So, by the Cauchy criterion, $\sum x_n y_n$ is a convergent series.

(c) This request is impossible. By the Algebraic Limit Theorem, if $\sum (x_n + y_n)$ converges and $\sum y_n$ converges, then $\sum (x_n + y_n) - \sum (y_n) = \sum x_n$ is also convergent.

(d) I think that this request is impossible as well. We know that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{n}$ converges. I have a hunch, that the the alternating series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^n x_n$ is always bound by $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^n /n$.

By the Algebraic Limit theorem, $\lim_{n \to \infty} 0 \le \lim_{n \to \infty} \le \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n}$, so $\lim_{n \to \infty}x_n = 0$. I would like to show that $(x_n)$ is a decreasing sequence.

Comment: For b), look at alternating series.

Comment: In $(d)$, consider a sequence that is $x_{2n}=\frac 1{2n},x_{2n+1}=0$.

Comment: i think (c) is reasoned incorrectly: it's not that $\sum (x_n + y_n) - \sum (y_n) = \sum x_n$ for whatever x and y and then $\sum$ x is also convergent. it's that because $\sum$ y and $\sum$ x+y converge that we say that  $\sum (x_n + y_n) - \sum (y_n)$ is equal the convergent series $\sum x_n$... or something like that. i think i'll just do some contrapositive though: $\sum (x_n + y_n)$ diverges if $\sum (x_n)$ or $\sum (y_n)$ diverges. let's see what José Carlos Santos has to say

Comment: @BCLC, for (c) I meant to use the result : if $\sum a_n = A$ and $\sum b_n = B$, then $\sum (c_1 a_n \pm c_2 b_n) = c_1 A + c_2 B$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(a) What you did is fine.

(b) $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}n$ converges, but $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}n\times(-1)^n$ diverges.

(c) What you did is fine.

(d) Take$$x_n=\begin{cases}\frac1n&\text{ if $n$ is odd}\\2^{-n}&\text{ otherwise.}\end{cases}$$

Comment: (b) That example is nice! At what point does the convergence proof, I was attempting to write for (b) fail? I have a wrong conclusion, so it must fail somewhere.

Comment: Both the first and the second inequalities are false.

Comment: Thank you. I now understand there is no such law or inequality, where $a \le b$ implies $\lvert{a}\rvert \le \lvert {b} \rvert$.

Comment: José Carlos Santos, i think (c) is reasoned incorrectly. am i wrong? OP seems to suggest that  '$\sum (x_n + y_n) - \sum (y_n) = \sum x_n$ for whatever x and y and then $\sum$ x is also convergent (because the two sums on LHS are convergent)' . it's that because $\sum$ y and $\sum$ x+y converge that we say that  $\sum (x_n + y_n) - \sum (y_n)$ is equal the convergent series $\sum x_n$... or something like that.( i think i'll just do some contrapositive though: $\sum (x_n + y_n)$ diverges if $\sum (x_n)$ or $\sum (y_n)$ diverges.)

Comment: @BCLC It seems to me that what the OP did is fine: if both series$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty(x_n+y_n)\text{ and }\sum_{n=0}^\infty x_n$$are convergent, then so is the series$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\bigl((x_n+y_n)-x_n\bigr),$$which is equal to $\sum_{n=0}^\infty y_n$.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos, (d) how do I see that the series $\sum (-1)^n x_n$ with terms $x_{2n+1} = \frac{1}{n}$ and $x_{2n}=2^{-n}$ is divergent?

Comment: The series with positive terms diverges and the series with negative ones diverges.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos, I see that. And the idea is that if $\sum x_n$ is convergent, and $\sum y_n$ is divergent, $\sum (x_n + y_n)$ is divergent. But, the two series are interlaced, and we need to rearrange terms. Can I freely do that?

Comment: @Quasar There is no problem, since, for each $N\in\Bbb N$,\begin{align}\sum_{n=0}^N(x_n+y_n)-\sum_{n=0}^Nx_n&=\sum_{n=0}^N\bigl((x_n+y_n)-x_n\bigr)\\&=\sum_{n=0}^Ny_n.\end{align}Since, since both limits$$\lim_{N\to\infty}\sum_{n=0}^N(x_n+y_n)\quad\text{and}\quad\lim_{N\to\infty}\sum_{n=0}^Nx_n$$exist, the limit$$\lim_{N\to\infty}\sum_{n=0}^Ny_n$$should also exist. But we are assuming that it doesn't.